# Estimating k of a chi-squared distribution using R logLikFun

Tags: r, chi-squared, estimation, log-likelihood

I have been tasked with estimating the degrees of freedom of the probability distribution function of several chi-squared distributions using maximum likelihood estimation.

I have narrowed down the log-likelihood function to the following:

(())=log(∏=1(;))
=∑=1log(/2−1−/2Γ(/2)2/2)

(2−1)∑=1log−12∑=1−log(Γ(/2))−2log(2)

[Picture version of log-likelihood function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzPwY.png)

However, I somehow fail to understand how to insert this function, in particular the log(Γ(/2) part, into R using the LogLikFun (for which I would later use maxLik R function to estimate the degrees of freedom *k*.

For instance, I have this for a log-likelihood for a normal distribution:

```
- 2*n*log(param[2]) - sum(((normal-param[1])/param[2])^2)
```

Does anyone know how one would translate the log-likelihood function of the chi-squared into R code - in particular the part with the Gamma function?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
ll_chisq <- function(k, X){
  n <- length(X)
  term1 <- -n*k*log(2)
  term2 <- -n*log(gamma(k/2))
  term3 <- (k/2 - 1)*sum(log(X))
  term4 <- -sum(X)/2
  term1 + term2 + term3 + term4
}
```